# I cannot use rmdir to remove a directory as there seems to be a file in the directory with the same name that cannot be deleted

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, command

Hi guys I am a complete beginner to programming and have tried to google this answer but with no joy.

I am following Zed Shaw's "Command Line Crash Course " and have hit a wall with rmdir.

I use a mac and know to delete hidden files like `.DS_Store` and have done so for my directory. However, it still says the directory is not empty and `ls -la` seems to show a file that shares the directory name:

See below for directory `joe`

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 MyLaptop staff  102  1 Apr 16:52 .

drwxr-xr-x  4 MyLaptop  staff  136 31 Mar 22:32 ..

drwxr-xr-x  3 MyLaptop  staff  102  1 Apr 16:51 joe
```

I have tried to remove this file but it will not allow me to and I cannot remove the directory, can anyone's suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is **not** a file. The `d` at the beginning of a line tells you that it is a directory. In fact it is the exact directory you are trying to delete.

The `rmdir` command requires that the `joe` directory be empty. To check if `joe` is empty use:

```
$ ls -la joe
```

Or move into that directory first:

```
$ cd joe
$ ls -la
```

You are instead using `ls -la` in the parent directory of `joe`, and hence `joe` itself is showing up in the contents.

So check which files are inside `joe` and delete them using `rm`.
The `.` and `..` entries don't really count as these are references to the current and parent directory.

---

Note that `rm` can also delete directories, so you could simply do `rm -r joe` to delete all the files inside `joe` *and* the `joe` directory itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still getting to grips with navigation but really appreciate the help.

Comment: "That is not a file". In Unix family systems, directories are file with the special feature to contain list of other files.

Comment: @Kenavoz Yeah, but in the end that's nitpicking. The OP pretty clearly uses the term file without knowledge of all the technicalities of Unix, and I believe adding all that here would just confuse a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

$ rm -r joe

The -r option to the rm command will recursively delete the contents of the directory, and the directory itself.

From the rm man page:

> ```
>      -r, -R, --recursive
>      remove directories and their contents recursively
> ```